# EnableWaterLock on Apple Watch deprecated are there any alternatives to lock the screen of the watch?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-6, waterlock

I just saw that [`WKExtension.shared.EnableWaterLock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension/2868458-enablewaterlock) is now deprecated.  I used this method in my workout apps to prevent accidentally tapping the screen and ending the workout etc.  Has it been replaced with any other method of locking the screen?

Comment: How would you accidentally end a workout when you need a swipe in a specific direction and a tap on a specific button? If you actually want to use it for its intended purpose, starting a swimming workout automatically puts on the water lock.

Comment: As my users can tell you @DávidPásztor it happens and this method has proven useful to prevent for the past 2 years

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That method wasn't removed from WatchKit, it was just moved from `WKExtension` to `WKInterfaceDevice` in watchOS 6.1.
See [`WKInterfaceDevice.enableWaterLock()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/3392965-enablewaterlock).

You can call it using `WKInterfaceDevice.current().enableWaterLock()`.